# Computing Area of a Square on a Surface given a Metric

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces

I have positive function $f$ of two variables, $u$ and $v$, and a surface $M$ such that the metric takes on the form $$ds^2 = f^2 \ du^2 + f^{-2} \ dv^2.$$  I want to compute the area of the square given by $0 \leq u,v \leq 1$.  Is this done by just integrating the metric over the square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the first fundamental form is $ds^2=Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2$. Comparing this with $ds^2$, one has
$$ E=f^2,F=0,G=f^{-2}. $$
Also note the area element is $dA=\sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv$. Then the area of the square given by $0≤u,v≤1$ is
$$ A=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv=1.$$